# How to output out parameter (type num_array) procedure results after executing it in declare in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a procedure, which returns num_array data type which is a specially created number data type. Procedures Spec:

```
 PROCEDURE GET_STATUS_LIST (P_MODUL_ID      IN     NUMBER,
                            P_DOCUMENT_ID   IN     NUMBER,
                            P_USER_ID       IN     NUMBER,
                            P_STATUS_LIST   OUT NUM_ARRAY);
```

So, I want to see what is the end result of my procedure.
I have tried either dbms_output, or select, or return sys_refcursor

```
 DECLARE
        alma    num_array;
        armud   SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
        schema.pk_common_confirmation.get_status_list (816,
                                                       17025214,
                                                       263,
                                                       alma);
    
        OPEN armud FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE (alma);
    
        --return armud;
        FOR t IN armud
        LOOP
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (t);
        END LOOP;
    END;
```

> Error message  PLS-00221: 'armud' is not a procedure or is undefined

```
DECLARE
    alma    num_array;
    armud   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN

    FOR t IN schema.pk_common_confirmation.get_status_list (816,
                                                            17025214,
                                                            263,
                                                            alma)
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (t);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

> Error message PLS-00456: item 'get_status_list ' is not a cursor

```
   DECLARE
        alma   num_array;
    BEGIN
        SELECT schema.pk_common_confirmation.get_status_list (816,
                                                              17025214,
                                                              263,
                                                              alma)
          FROM DUAL;
    END;
```

> Error message ORA-00904: invalid identifier

```
DECLARE
    alma    num_array;
    armud   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    turanbank.pk_common_confirmation.get_status_list (816,
                                                      17025214,
                                                      263,
                                                      alma);

    FOR t IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE (alma))
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (t);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

> Error message PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to
> 'PUT_LINE'

Are there other ways I can output or see or select procedure results?

I don't know how to resolve these errors.
Any help would be appreciated

- I have found one way of returning procedure results for this data type. I thought, if it's num_array as there's an array in its name, I can get the result by index.

```sql
DECLARE
    alma    num_array;
    armud   SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    schema.pk_common_confirmation.get_status_list (816,
                                                      17025214,
                                                      263,
                                                      alma);

    FOR t IN 1..alma.count
    LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (alma(t));
    END LOOP;
END;
```

```
DBMS_OUTPUT : 
1441
1442
1701
1741
1801
2582
```

But still, I would like to know any other ways of doing it, so if there is any suggestions, please do tell

Comment: Try `FOR t IN SELECT * FROM TABLE (alma) LOOP ...`.

Comment: @Codo still nothing. Maybe, my select returns more than 1 column, so put_line can't accept multiple rows?

Comment: Read the error message: you have made progress. The loop works. The problem is now down to *put_line*. You need to create a string from the individual fields of the record, e.g. `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(t.P_MODUL_ID || ', ' || t.P_DOCUMENT_ID || ', ' || t.P_USER_ID);`

Comment: @Codo I understand what you mean. But P_MODUL_ID and so on doesn't work, saying, P_MODUL_ID must be declared. The problem is that select doesn't return given parameters. And I'm not sure about what column name will be returned.

Comment: We shouldn't collect apples and pears together as proverb suggests :)

Comment: Oops, I got the wrong field names. What's the exact type of `NUM_ARRAY`? If it's an array or table of numbers (and not an array of some record type), then the correct statement is `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(t.COLUMN_VALUE);` (see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/pseudocolumns004.htm#SQLRF50950).